# Singleton's instance and scoped_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, singleton, smart-pointers

I have a singleton with a following structure:

```
// Hpp
class Root : public boost::noncopyable
{
    public:
        ~Root();

        static Root &Get();

        void Initialize();
        void Deinitialize();

    private:
        Root();  // Private for singleton purposes
        static boost::scoped_ptr<Root> mInstance;

        Manager1 *mManager1;
        Manager2 *mManager2;
};


// Cpp
boost::scoped_ptr<Root> Root::mInstance;

Root::Root()
{
    // [!!!]
    mInstance = this;

    // Managers are using `mInstance` in their constructors
    mManager1 = new Manager1();
    mManager2 = new Manager2();

    mInstance->Initialize();
}

Root::~Root() { delete mManager1; delete mManager2; }

Root &Root::Get()
{
    if (mInstance == nullptr) mInstance = boost::scoped_ptr<Root>(new Root());
    return *mInstance;
}
```

The idea is to remove instance automatically when program exists. Look at line marked `[!!!]` : `mInstance = this`. I have to do this because `mManager1` and `mManager2` are using `mInstance` in their purposes in ctor.

The problem is how to use `this` with `boost::scoped_ptr`? In `shared_ptr` case there is `enable_shared_from_this` class from boost which allows to get what I need. But what to do in my case?

Comment: meh, I stopped reading after the word **singleton**! Why???

Comment: @tony-the-lion let's speak only on the topic.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply pass `this` to the constructors? It's simpler, and it reduces coupling.

Comment: There is an easier way to guarantee destruction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/14065

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply have the constructors take the `Root` as argument, and then pass `this` to them:

```
Root::Root() {
    mManager1 = new Manager1(this);
    mManager2 = new Manager2(this);    
    Initialize();
}
```

One additional advantage of this is that you don't get the other classes coupled to the singleton secretly.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's a good idea, I'll do everything this way. But I'm still interested what to do in my case?